# Flask, почему при отправке запроса возвращает ошибку 404?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Вот вьюшка, показывает запись(стих) и содержит форму отправки комментария:

```
@app.route('/comment_entry/<int:id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def comment_entry(id):
    title = 'Показать стих'
    comment_entry = Entry.query.get_or_404(id)
    form = CommentForm()
    if current_user and form.validate_on_submit():
        comment_add = Comment(body=form.body.data, 
                              pub_date=datetime.now(),
                              author_comment=current_user, 
                              entry_comment=comment_entry)
        db.session.add(comment_add)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Вы добавили свой комментарий')
        return redirect(url_for('comment_entry', id=comment_entry.id))
    return render_template('entry/comment_entry.html',
                           title=title, entry=comment_entry, form=form)
```

При отправке комментария получаю ошибку 404.

Вот часть шаблона этой вьюшки:

```
{{ form.hidden_tag() }}
{{ form.body.label }}:
{{ form.body(cols=52, rows=4) }}
{% for error in form.errors.body %}
    {{ error }}
{% endfor %}
```

Почему я получаю такую ошибку?

Comment: Весь шаблон покажите.

Comment: Очевидно, что причина 404 ошибки - результат метода, get_or_404().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На все 100% уверен, что в атрибуте `action` тэга `form` идентификтора нет. Как следствие, аргументу `id` в функции `comment_entry` взяться неоткуда, поэтому он равен `None`. Естественно, `Entry.query.get_or_404(None)` выбросит 404-ю.